# Referencing Other Data from Other Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need help in regards to pulling data from other models and proper referencing help in Rails. For example I have a Rails app where it holds race information. Here I have Cars, Car Class, Events, and Racing. I have it to where I can create a car that is part of a Car Class, however I do not know how I would do the Events and Racing part.  I hope this all makes sense as I'm still trying to wrap my head around it myself. I'm using Rails version `4.1.6`.

*Also if someone could come up with a better title for this question I would appreciate it.*

**Car Class:**
This is the class that a car belongs to.  All cars have to be in a class. This should hold all the information about the car class.

**Model:**

```
class CarClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

---

**Cars:**
Cars belong in a class as you can see in the models for `CarClass` and `Car`. This should hold all the details about the cars.

**Model:**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :car_class
 end
```

---

**Event:**
An event is where a car class will race. It will hold the event details, however the class and car details will be held by the `CarClass` and `Car` as mentioned above. It should be possible to get a list of all the cars for the event. I assume `Event` will have many `Racing`.

---

**Racing**
This should hold stats about the race on a per car basis. For example what place they came in, track times, etc.  I assume `Racing` will belong to `Event`.

Comment: class Car < ActiveRecord::Base       belongs_to :cars  end it can't belong to itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty classic `has_many through:` situation. Which is a many-to-many relationship between the two models with an intermediate model acting as a join table. Using a separate model here for the join table will allow you to store additional data for racings and not just the connection between the cars and events.

You could do the following:

```
class Racing < AR::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < AR::Base
  has_many :racings
  has_many :cars, through: :racings
end

class Car < AR::Base
  has_many :racings
  has_many :events, through: :racings

  belongs_to :car_class 
end

class CarClass < AR::Base
  has_many :cars
end
```

You can read more about Rails' associations [in the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

This will allow you to access events from cars and vice versa. Also this way you can reach car classes from event. For example the first car's class of the first event:

```
Event.first.cars.first.car_class
```

When you loop through associations don't forget to use `includes` where appropriate.

Comment: How would the Car Class play into this? I assume Car still `belongs_to car_class` right?

Comment: I'm sure this is probably correct so I'm going to mark it as the answer.

Do you know how I would do an event form for this? For example if I choose a car class on an event I would like it to add all the cars from that car class to `racing` and have them under that event. Right now I can only think of maybe a `for @cars.each` do and then to loop through all the cars in that class and add them one by one somehow..but this does not seem correct to me.

This seems like another question...let me know if I should create one.

Comment: Yes this is probably a separate question. When you create an event you could just do `event.cars << car_class.cars`. See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C